# Hybrid authentication scenario - Azure AD B2C and Azure AD

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have this scenario where we have to authenticate corporate users via Azure AD, but the external users via Azure AD B2C - all from the same login screen.

There are a few web applications which will share this capability. The applications come from various technology stacks, ranging from .Net to Java-Spring + Angular 2.

What is your recommended approach for this?
Apologies, if this question has already been asked and answered, but couldn't find much guidance on this. 
Will MSAL library solve this? Besides, there aren't any MSAL implementation for Java yet.
Will Azure AD B2C Premium support this?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 5):

At this time your only option is to implement support for both Azure AD & Azure AD B2C independently in your applications.  You must ask the user to select between the two identity providers, and then invoke the correct one.

There are plans to add support for Azure AD org users as an identity provider in Azure AD B2C, at which point two integrations will not be necessary.  However that capability isn't in the near future.

I slapped together a bit of guidance on how to support both in a .NET application, perhaps that will get you on the right track: https://github.com/dstrockis/AAD-B2C-Hybrid

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me...Is this based off one of the standard azure ad samples?

Comment: Cloned, re-configured, but unable to able to get this working... Anything besides ida:Tenant and ida:ClientId need to be changed (assuming I have setup the relevant b2c policies)?

Comment: There looks to be an approach in preview at the moment that does this via custom policies. I've yet to test, but looks promising. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom

Answer (score 1):

To use the Azure AD for corporate users login and Azure B2C for external users you need to Configure the following

**Step 1 -** Configure Identity providers
If you are using the Identity Experience Framework policy

- Create Azure AD Claims Provider using `OpenIdConnect` Protocol for Corporate user Authentication
- Create Azure AD B2C Claims Provider using `login-NonInteractive` TechnicalProfile for External user Authentication
- Add the above two to `<ClaimsProviderSelections>` under `<UserJourneys>` --> `<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signupsignin">`

Example:

```
      <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="AADExchange" />
      </ClaimsProviderSelections>
      <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
      </ClaimsExchanges>
    </OrchestrationStep>
```

If you are using User flows then you need to configure the following

- Register the Azure AD as a new `OpenID Connect provider` in Identity Providers of Azure AD B2C
- In the User Flow policy, Choose `Email Signin` under Local Accounts for External user authentication
- In the User Flow policy, Choose the newly created `OpenID Connect provider` for the Corporate User Authentication

**Step 2 -** Create a App registration

**Step 3 -** Configure the Redirect URIs for the app created in App Registration to your Application URL's

**Step 4 -** When you test the policy, you will be presented with 2 options, username and password for the External user authentication where the user use the username and password configured for them in Azure AD B2C and the second option is a Link at the bottom off the signin page to login with Azure AD. When users click on this link, they will be taken to the Azure AD Login page for authentication.

Refer to the below link for more detailed configuration steps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=app-reg-ga

Answer (score 0):

If you offer a Software as a Service (SaaS) application to many organizations, you can configure your application to accept sign-ins from any Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant. This configuration is called making your application multi-tenant. Users in any Azure AD tenant will be able to sign in to your application after consenting to use their account with your application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant