# How to authenticate corporate users with Azure AD, and also external users?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c, azure-active-directory

We need to authenticate both corporate users and external users (partner, customers, third party) into the same application.
Corporate users will authenticate using Azure AD, I want them to have SSO experience.
For external users I was thinking of Azure AD B2C.

The application is built with Asp.NET MVC/WebApi + AngularJs.

For the scenario described above, I understand I will need 2 different Azure AD tenants.
I'm planning to use the Microsoft new Authentication Library MSAL, but I can't find how to configure 2 tenants.

What is the recommended approach for login both corporate and external users ?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: there is a good documentation on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650307.aspx  hope this helps

Comment: Based on my understanding, the application for customers should be different for enterprise user. Two applications are recommend for this scenario. You may share more detail about the scenario you were handling.

Comment: That may be true for Customers and Partners, but we have external third party resources that must work with the current app but are not part of the corporate AD.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, you must treat Azure AD & B2C as two separate identity providers in your application.  I've created a quick & dirty example of such dual integration in a web app [here](https://github.com/dstrockis/AAD-B2C-Hybrid).  In an AngularJS app, or in an app that uses MSAL, the integrations will be different.  But the high level pattern will be the same.

With this approach, you'll have to ask users which type of account they want to sign-in with, so you know which provider to invoke.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834353/hybrid-authentication-scenario-azure-ad-b2c-and-azure-ad

Comment: Could we simply add the external users accounts into the same Azure AD ? What are the implications ? **Note the Azure AD is synced from an Windows Server AD, and is also used by Office 365.

Comment: No, regular Azure AD tenants do not support consumer accounts.

Comment: Isn't MSAL supposed to unify MS Account, Azure AD and Azure AD B2C ? Why do we need to manually build an hybrid solution ? I though MSAL would manage all this...

Comment: It will in time, but it's not there yet.